# thunder.dll is detected as a trojan virus by AVG whenever IE8 is opened

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, trojan, avg-antivirus

Whenever I open IE8, or a new tab in IE8, AVG will prompt a warning about **thunder.dll** as posing a threat and says that it is a trojan horse.

The file is located at: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\thunder.dll`

Is this something I should be worried about? What should I do?

I am using Windows 7 64bit with Internet Explorer 8.

Answer (score 1):

Actually,

[THUNDER.DLL](http://www.prevx.com/filenames/1552208996945183432-X1/THUNDER.DLL.html) has been seen to perform the following behavior:

```
* The Process is packed and/or encrypted using a software packing process
* The Process is polymorphic and can change its structure
* Creation and Registration of a Browser Helper Object in Internet Explorer
* Enables an In Process Object/Server - Common with DLL Injections
* Registers a Dynamic Link Libray (DLL) File
* Registers a Dynamic Link Library File
* Found on infected systems and resists interrogation by security products
```

Thus, you should use some [removal tools](http://www.exterminate-it.com/malpedia/remove-thunder) .also I think that AVG could be able to remove it.

Comment: I tried to use "Move to Vault" option in AVG and the system hangs. I restart the windows, and open IE8. The next thing is that the warning prompts up again.

Comment: have you tried to remove with removal tools heh ?